Question about the recursion theorm
I am trying to solve a probelom using the recursion theorm and I have 2 questions.
$Theorem:$ for any $F:V\to V$ class function there is a unique clas function $G:ON\to V$ such that $(\forall\alpha):G(\alpha)=F((G(\beta):\beta<\alpha))$.
Where $V$ is the class such that $V=\left\{{x\mid x=x}\right\}$ and $OD$ is the class of all ordinals.
I am trying to solve the following question using that theorem:
Any countable and not finite ($|A|=\aleph_0$) directed set A with no max element has a dominate series denote by $\left\langle x_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N{}\right\rangle $ such that for any $n\in \mathbb N:$ $x_{n+1}>x_n$.
Definitions:
A directed set is a poset such that for any $a,b\in A$ exists $c\in A$ such that $b\le c$ and $a\le c$.
$B\subset A$ is called dominate if for every $a\in A$ exists $d\in D$ such that $a\le d$.
Attempt using the theorm:
define $F:V\to V$ such that:
$F\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
a_{0} & x=()\\
k_{n}=\min\left(\left\{ k\in A\mid\left(k>k_{n-1}\right)\wedge\left(k>\left\{ a_{d}\mid0\le d\le n-1\right\} \right)\right\} \right) & x=(k_{0},\dots,k_{n-1})\\
0 & else
\end{cases}$
from that theorm exists $G:\omega \to A$ such that $g\left(n\right)=F\left(g\left(0\right),\dots,g\left(n-1\right)\right)$.
Claims: $g(n)$ exists since the set has no maximal element and its infinite there is always a bigger element, hence using the axiom of choice we can pick such $g(n)$.
Denote: $\left\langle g(n)\mid n\in\mathbb N{}\right\rangle  $
by induction we can show the premise.
My questions:
Is my function F well defined? I understand how to do "normal recursion" such as I was using before this theorem from set theory but I am having an hard time formalizing it to the theorem.
I was told I can't do induction on the size of the series and I can't for example proof by indction on the size of the seires that this kind of element exsits:
$k_{n}=\min\left(\left\{ k\in A\mid\left(k>k_{n-1}\right)\wedge\left(k>\left\{ a_{d}\mid0\le d\le n-1\right\} \right)\right\} \right)$ and let it be the next element in my series.
I was told that I have to use the recursion theorm, I can't really grasp my head why wouldn't induction work.
